# Rails routing name convention

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

For some reason the conventional path names for a particular controller are not working? (Rails 3.1)

I created a controller using ryan bates nifty scaffold. Just a controller, no underlying model.

in the controller I have

```
class ProjectTemplatesController < ApplicationController
# a bunch of stuff

  def new
    @project = Project.new
  end

#more stuff
end
```

in my view (app/views/project_templates/index.html.erb) I have:

```
<p><%= link_to "New Project Templates", new_project_templates_path %></p>
```

however I get the error

```
undefined local variable or method `new_project_templates_path' for #<#<Class:0x2ab9c24>:0x2ab80e0>
```

in my routes.rb file I declared the controller as a resource like all the others

```
resources :project_templates
```

**If I change the link to use**

`<%= link_to "New Project Templates", {:controller=>"project_templates, :action=>"new"} %>`

**then it works perfectly?!** Why doesnt the naming convension of action_controller_path work in this case?

Comment: does new_project_template_path work? If so, it would be due to the inflection libraries

Comment: Have you run `rake routes` already, to check if the route exists as you think it does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find all of the routes and their names on the command line with `rake routes`.

Rails knows about the pluralization you are using so it could be magically removing it and naming the route `new_project_template_path` without the 's'?

Comment: Yes it was indeed due to the pluralization, new_project_template_path works just fine. Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 3):

A simple addendum to the previous posts noting the possibility to run rake routes. If on a POSIX system, run the result through grep or some other text filter.

```
rake routes | grep project
```

or

```
bundle exec rake routes | grep project
```

Generated routes can get to be very plentiful in large projets so I suggest becoming a command line tools guru in order to efficiently data crunch.

Comment: Now you do not need to use `bundle exec`, simply use `bundle install --binstubs` and `export PATH=./bin:$PATH`. What I have done in the past is simply add the export line to my `.rvmrc` file and add `bin` the `.gitignore`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `resources :project_templates`, you could safely to do something like this:

```
link_to "All Project Templates", :project_templates
link_to "New Project Template", [:new, :project_template]
link_to "Edit Project Template", [:edit, @project_template]
link_to "Show Project Template", @project_template
link_to "Delete Project Template", @project_template, :method => :delete
form_for ProjectTemplate.new do |f|
form_for @projectTemplate do |f|
```

This way, you don't have to remember the plural or singular problem.

One more thing is that you actually could wrap them all in `[]` so that you don't worry about them.

```
link_to "All PT", [:project_templates]
link_to "Show PT", [@project_template]
```